# how to get compiz visual effects at startup

Tags: 11.04, compiz

Compiz visual was working perfectly just days ago after a restart (no update nothing) it stopped working at startup, i have to run "compiz --replace" for it to work again and get recognized

I would like to have my compiz visual affects to work spontaneously on startup

Running ubuntu 11.04

thanks

Comment: OK figure out a work around am not sure its the best way but it works 

I added to the startup application "compiz --replace" 

Working fine now 

If anyone have a better solution (if this is a bad one) please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "compiz --replace" at Startup Applications is a perfectly fine workaround. I found that sometimes this problem is caused by some configuration file. See this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/compiz/+bug/577482) at launchpad.

In my case, the problem was caused by a file named "gnome-wm.desktop" at "~/.local/share/applications/" and was solved after deleting it. The content of this file was:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=gnome-wm
Hidden=true
Name=Window Manager
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-session
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=2.32.0
X-GNOME-Provides=windowmanager
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-2.0
```